# Check support for variable length array in C

Tags: c, arrays, c99

Is there a standard macro to check support of variable length arrays in C code? It it enough to check for c99 (`__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`) in all widely used compilers?

Comment: Since you've tagged C99, you are guaranteed to have VLAs if your compiler is C99 compliant.

Comment: Better don't use them.

Comment: Yes. I know it is a c99 feature. And as I know, for example msvc that doesn't support them doesn't declare macros that determine c99. I just wanted to check that all compilers do the same. I better a bit rewrite my question.

Comment: You want a macro that will cause a compile-time error if a VLA would cause a compile-time error?  Why not just try to compile a VLA and see if it causes an error?

Comment: The non-compliant MSVC does not need a macro. It doesn't compile.

Comment: You would only need a macro in C11 when VLAs became optional. Therefore they are not standard so as @i486 says - don't use them.

Comment: No I don't want a compile time error.

Comment: I want to use it in **#ifdef**

Comment: @abelenky: In some cases, it may be possible to write code which will work with or without VLA support.  For example use either `int foo[x];` or `int *foo = malloc(x * sizeof (int));` (and later free the storage), depending upon whether VLA suport exists.  If VLA support exists, and a programmer is willing to chance a stack overflow, the VLA approach may be faster, but code should be usable (but perhaps not as fast) even without VLA support.

Comment: @supercat:  Perfectly valid points, but was not at all clear from the original question.  I thought the user wanted to fail if VLAs were not supported, and nothing in the question said differently.

Comment: @abelenky: The question doesn't specify a particular reason for wanting to know, but I don't see anything that would suggest the intention is purely to have code fail compilation on systems where it would fail compilation anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the C11 specification §6.10.8.3

> The following macro names are conditionally defined by the
>   implementation:
>   [...]
>
> `__STDC_NO_VLA__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably
>   modified types.

So if `__STDC_VERSION__ > 201000L` you need to check `__STDC_NO_VLA__`.

Otherwise, if `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L` VLAs should work, but you'll get a compile time error if the compiler is non-compliant.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like what I was looking for. I'll examine it.