# Dynamic memory allocation for two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c

I want to allocate memory for a two-dimensional array (matrix) and write the sums of the diagonals in a separate one-dimensional array. So my code has an array of pointers to pointers,

```
int N, ** matrix = NULL;
matrix = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
```

I fill it and then I create an array to store the sums of the diagonals,

```
int diag = 2 * N - 1;
int *diagonals = NULL;
diagonals = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * diag);
```

but when I want to write a value into an array, something goes wrong, the values just don't get written into the array; I don't know why.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N, ** matrix = NULL;
    printf("Input the number of rows\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    printf("\n");
    // Memory allocation for the array of pointers to pointers
    
    matrix = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
    if (matrix != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            *(matrix + i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 14 - 4;
                printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        int diag = 2 * N - 1;
        int *diagonals = NULL;
        diagonals = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * diag);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    diagonals[i+j] += matrix[i][j];;
            }
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < diag; i++) {
                printf("diagonals[%d] - %d\n",i, *(diagonals+i));
        }

    }
    else
        printf("Not enough memory.. oops..\n");
}
```

Comment: `*(matrix + i)` is a really smug way of writing `matrix[i]`, IMO.

Comment: You did not initialize values in the `diagonals` array before the loops. Those loops use `+=` to modify the _existing_ value. You're clearly assuming the values start off initially as zero, but they are uninitialized. You must initialize them explicitly with a loop, or `memset`, or allocate with `calloc`.

Comment: And since this is tagged `c`, you [don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2005038) the result of `malloc`.

Comment: why diags = 2* N - 1 and not 2*N

Comment: You could save yourself quite a lot of code by declaring and allocating `matrix` with a simple `int (*matrix)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof *matrix);`

Comment: @tstanisl I'd go even further. Since all the rows are same length, I'd just use a flat 1D array and some simple arithmetic when indexing.

Comment: @DanMašek, maybe, but manual calculations of indices becomes very cumbersome for 3D and more tensors. VLA **types** were introduced to make handling such entities much easier.

Comment: @marco-a Nah it's just a needlessly unreadable way. The really smug way would be `i[matrix]`.

Comment: So is this supposed to print all the diagonals of a matrix or calculate the sum of them? I'm not sure if it does either of that.

Comment: @Lundin I agree. It's not smug but needlessly unreadable... wasn't exactly sure how to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `diagonals` is allocated with `malloc()` which **does not** initialize the memory. You should use `calloc()` which initializes the memory with zeros:

```
diagonals = calloc(diag, sizeof *diagonals);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following loop assumes that each element of `diagonals` was initialized to zero, but you performed no such initialization. As a result, they are *uninitialized* and will contain whatever value happens to be sitting in the newly-allocated memory.

```
diagonals = malloc(sizeof(int) * diag);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        diagonals[i+j] += matrix[i][j];;
    }
}
```

You have several options for zero-initialization:

1. Use `memset` to zero the memory, after allocation:

   ```
    diagonals = malloc(sizeof(int) * diag);
    memset(diagonals, 0, sizeof(int) * diag);
   ```
2. Initialize values in a loop:

   ```
    diagonals = malloc(sizeof(int) * diag);
    for (int i = 0; i < diag; i++) diagonals[i] = 0;
   ```
3. Allocate with `calloc`:

   ```
    diagonals = calloc(diag, sizeof(int));
   ```

Note that in all cases, you should be checking the result of allocation. If it fails and returns NULL, you should not attempt to access memory via that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not answer the question but I would suggest using real 2D arrays instead of arrays of pointers. To dynamically allocate the 2D array you need to use a pointer to array.

```
    int (*matrix)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof(*matrix));
```

You will have only one allocation and one free. Fever levels of indirection.

Comment: The use of VLA should include a test for availability, since its support is optional in C.2011 and above. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988521/check-support-for-variable-length-array-in-c

Comment: @jxh, support for VLA typew is going to be mandatory in C23. There will be no need for this check anymore

Comment: @tstanisl The references I have found refer to variably-modified types being mandatory, not VLA. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @jxh, VLA means an object of "VLA type" which is a *subtype* of VMT family. In C23 one can create any VLA type: `typedef int T[n];`. However, only creation of *an object* of VLA type with **automatic** storage are going to be optional. So `T a;` will be  optional while support for `T *a = malloc(sizeof *a);` will be mandatory.

Comment: @tstanisl *VLA means an object of "VLA type"* -- got it, thanks.